# C# EF 6.1 - Strage behavior of conditional query with delegate

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I've noticed a very strange behavior of the Entity Framework 6.1. My goal is to conditionally count some rows from a table filled with 2 millions records. Firstly, I've have used simple method to obtain the desired value:

```
private void SeedsQuery(object o)
{
    StatProperty property = o as StatProperty;

    using (SteelPoppyContext context = new SteelPoppyContext())
    {
            property.Value = context.QueuedGames.Count(game => game.IsSeed);
    }
}
```

This code runs about 1 sec and provides desired result without using any memory. Now, I would like to implement more conditions to the same query using switch statement. The easiest way is to use a delegate which is provided each time the query is ran. To simplify our case, I've prepared a simple example.

```
private void SeedsQuery(object o)
{
    StatProperty property = o as StatProperty;
    Func<QueuedGame, bool> predicate = new Func<QueuedGame, bool>(game => game.IsSeed);

    using (SteelPoppyContext context = new SteelPoppyContext())
    {
            property.Value = context.QueuedGames.Count(predicate);
    }
}
```

This method should do exactly the same thing as the one above it. However, when I run this code, the query execution takes about 1 min, and used memory jumps to 1GB. I'm guessing that Entity Framework is fetching all the data from the database and then the condition is checked. Is there any explanation to such behavior?

Comment: EF uses expression trees to translate C# code to SQL, as Darin points out, you are not using an Expression in your delegate, thus EF does the equivalent of a .AsEnumerable() in order to translate it to a non-expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This method should do exactly the same thing as the one above it

Actually not at all. The method you have written is not equivalent to the original code you had.

Your original code was using the [`Count`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534807(v=vs.100).aspx) overload taking an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` and not a `Func<T, bool>`. So if you want to write an equivalent code make sure that you do so:

```
private void SeedsQuery(object o)
{
    StatProperty property = o as StatProperty;
    Expression<Func<QueuedGame, bool>> predicate = x => x.IsSeed;

    using (SteelPoppyContext context = new SteelPoppyContext())
    {
            property.Value = context.QueuedGames.Count(predicate);
    }
}
```

Notice that the `predicate` variable that I used in my example is an `Expression<Func<QueuedGame, bool>>` instead of just a `Func<QueuedGame, bool>`.

Now EF will be able to build the proper SQL instead of loading your entire table in memory and then just counting the records after having wasted everything.